# Probability that the majority of 3 classifiers are wrong

Tags: probability, statistics

3 classifiers. Each classifier has $0.7$ accuracy and makes its error independently.

**How do I calculate the probability that the majority of three classifiers are wrong?**

*how I'm trying to solve it:*

(3 choose 2) * 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.7 * 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.3

Comment: What made you decide to use this particular formula?

Comment: I think the majority is 3 choose 2. Then I multiply by what is left times the .7 accuracy. That came into my head when I saw the problem, I am not sure it is an actual formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Hint:* Majority means it could potentially be either $3$ or $2$. The probability of majority of the classifiers being wrong is the probability that either $2$ are wrong or all $3$ are wrong. 
 *Example:* Probability that $k$ out of $n$ independent trials of a random experiment are successful, with the probability of success being $p$ is ${n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.

Comment: I don't understand that formula. I agree with the `n choose k` part, but I don't understand the rest.

Comment: The rest is just an hint as to this particular experiment is equivalent to an experiment with a Binomial Distribution. Given that there are $k$ successes out of $n$ trials, the probability of such an occurrence is $p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ since the trials are independent. This distribution just tells you as to how many of those events can be accounted for and that is ${n\choose k}$. And why the downvotes?

Comment: $n = 2$ and $k = 3$ but what does $p = ?$

Comment: $p$ is the probability of success/failure (depending upon the way you want to interpret) that you consider for the experiment. Here in our question the accuracy is $0.7$ and hence $p=0.7$ which is the probability of success and $1-p=0.3$ which is the probability of failure.

Comment: So I was pretty close with what I had above.

Comment: The simplified form would be ${3\choose 2} 0.3^2 0.7 + {3\choose 3} 0.3^3$ and that is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked/answered here, but with 17 classifiers. Simply use their solution and change from 17 to 3 to apply to here.
[To improve the accuracy, a majority vote is taken. What is the probability of an incorrect classification?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712689/to-improve-the-accuracy-a-majority-vote-is-taken-what-is-the-probability-of-an)

Comment: mark as duplicate instead of answering